# Exercise IX.13 in Taylor's Practical Foundations - Fibrations of groups and Jordan-Hölder

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

*Practial Foundations, Exercise IX.13. (For group theorists.)* Use the fact that fibrations of groups are surjective homomorphisms and that this class is closed under pullbacks to prove the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

How to solve this exercise?

I'm very curious about it and have no idea what to do. It seems suspicious that pullback stability (which is what I assume was meant by "closed under pullbacks") of surjections would by itself imply Jordan-Hölder. Surjections are pullback stable in the category of sets, and I think in the category of monoids as well. On the other hand I don't think monoids admit a Jordan-Hölder theorem. (There's a paper by Borceux which shows Jordan-Hölder holds in any semi-abelian category, but monoids are not even protomodular.)

Comment: Surjections are stable under pullbacks in monoids, but they need not be fibrations...